# aws ec2 as login as root on WinSCP - Received too large (... B) SFTP packet. Max supported packet size is 102400 B

Tags: amazon-ec2, winscp

I wanted to upload my edited file anywhere in the server so im looking a way to login as root in WinSCP.

I tried to login as root in WinSCP with my aws-ec2 credentials and it keep responding with an error message of 
**Received too large (... B) SFTP packet. Max supported packet size is 102400 B**

Note: I can login with my ec2-user

Answer (score 4):

it seems i can login as root and successfully edit and upload my file in WinSCP with this

## SOLUTION 1:

(downside, shell login will not work, only login on WinSCP/sftp)

> Change the ForceCommand line in /etc/ssh/sshd_config to:  "ForceCommand internal-sftp" 
>   https://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2918

EDIT:

## SOLUTION 2:

- login as ec2-user in shell
- sudo su
- cd /root/.ssh

> create backup for authorized_keys

- cp authorized_keys authorized_keys.backup

> edit your authorized_keys

- vi authorized_keys

You will see this chunk of words inside. REMOVE IT.

> no-port-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,command="echo 'Please login as the user \"ec2-user\" rather than the user \"root\".';echo;sleep 10"

- `Shift Q`, then `wq`, press `enter` (saved!)
- try to login as root